# Why can't I use send_keys() for an element out of a list in selenium

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, webdriver

I am using Selenium in python with chrome webdriver. I want to send keys to certain input fields, and I can do so if I find each individual item by it's name or id. However I would like to do something more like:

```
fields = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("input")
fields[0].send_keys("foo")
```

However, this gives me:

```
"selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: 
 cannot focus element"
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: This probably means the element is hidden and cannot be focused to enter text

Comment: I don't think that is right because I can find the element and send keys to it by using the find_element_by_name() method. I only get that error when I get the input list and try to send keys to the individual elements.

Comment: Okie that gives some good hint to what is wrong. Please add the html of your page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So when you use `find_element_by_name`

```
driver.find_element_by_name("xyz").send_keys("foo")
```

consider the below html

```
<input class="input" type=hidden name=iamhidden>
<input class="input" type=text name=xyz>
```

Now if I use

```
fields = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("input")
fields[0].send_keys("foo")
```

This is not guarantying in any way that the first element I am getting is the same as `<input class="input" type=text name=xyz>` because now I am making a generic query which will return multiple elements. If you really want to test it out use

```
fields = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("input")
for field in fields:
    try:
       field.send_keys("foo")
    except:
       pass
```

Now if the element sets `foo` for the textbox you were interested in then you know you used the wrong index